# Proving a set $X$ is dense in the normed space $(\ell_1, \| \cdot \|_1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X= \{x= (x_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}  : \exists \ C>0 \ \text{such that} \ |x_k| \leq \frac{C}{k^2} \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N} \} $. 
We need to prove that the set $X$ is dense in $\ell_1$. 
So far, I have proved that the set $X$ is a subspace of $\ell_1$ and that $\overline{X} \subseteq \ell_1$, so it remains to show that $\ell_1 \subseteq \overline{X}$.

Aso, I'm wondering if the space $(X,\| \cdot \|_1)$ is complete.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A subspace of a complete metric space is complete if and only if it is closed. Thus, $X$ cannot be complete with respect to the metric induced by $\lVert \cdot \rVert_1$ unless $X = \ell_1$.

Comment: I thought that only one direction holds: if a subspace of a complete metric space is closed, then it is complete.

Comment: A complete subspace is closed regardless of whether the superspace is complete. Think about a sequence in the subspace that converges to a point in the superspace. Then that sequence is Cauchy, therefore...

Comment: Well, suppose $S \subseteq X$ where $X$ is complete and $S$ is complete. Now take a convergent sequence in $X$ whose elements are all in $S$. Any convergent sequence is Cauchy, and $S$ is complete, so this sequence has its limit in $S$. Thus $S$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Hint: any sequence with finite support is an element of $X$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I still can't see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C_{c}=\{x=(x_{n})\mid\exists N\mbox{ such that }x_{n}=0\mbox{ whenever }n>N\}.$
It is well-known that $C_{c}$ is dense in $l^{1}$ (given an element
in $l^{1}$, we find a corresponding element in $C_{c}$ by truncating
the tail of the given element).

Therefore, it suffices to show that $C_{c}\subseteq X$. Let $x\in C_{c}$
be given. Choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_{n}=0$ whenever $n>N$.
Choose $M>0$ such that $|x_{n}|\leq M$ for all $n$. Let $C=N^{2}M$.
Clearly, $|x_{n}|\leq M=\frac{C}{N^{2}}\leq\frac{C}{n^{2}}$ for each
$n\leq N$. For $n>N,$ we have $|x_{n}|=0\leq\frac{C}{n^{2}}$ too.
Therefore $x\in X$. This shows that $C_{c}\subseteq X$.